# Migrating mvc2 to mvc4 with ef/codefirst and sql server to inmemory database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, in-memory-database

I have ASP.NET mvc2 web application already running in two machines and connected with sql server. My database is 200mb at max. I want to migrate my web application to use mvc4 and EF and I also want to use some in memory database by droping sql server.

I checked on internet and i can migrate my application to mvc4 and EF but I could not find help about which in memomry databse i can use with EF/Codefirst. Also  how can I backup inmemory database to some web based storage as Amazon S3 or Azure storage?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you want to use an in memory database? Sql databses have great reliability and querying capabilities.

When using two servers, an in memory database isn't going to work since the memory will be local to each server. You can use a distributed cache or something to make this work.

The Entity Framework isn't suited for this scenario. It is an object relational *database* mapper. It makes no sense to use this with an in memory database. An ORM translates objects to a relational store (like a database). In memory you only deal with objects so you don't need an ORM.

If your database is only 200mb you will not have any performance problems. A database is optimized for your scenario and an ORM like the Entity Framework will speed up your development time.

Comment: I worked on a project where the unit testing was unacceptably slow for some tests using anything but an in-memory data store.

Comment: @CarlG Unit testing is a whole different story. When running unit tests you should avoid using a database. If you use a database, you are running integration tests. There should be only a few integration tests in your project. Unit tests can be run constantly (especially when using Test Driven Development). Integration tests can be run less frequently on a build server.